# $u \sim v \implies v \sim u$ Vector Spaces, Basis, Dimension, Rank Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, proof-writing, vectors

(I'm not sure if the tittle is a good description for this question, since I'm not even sure what the question is really asking. Hopefully you can point me in the right direction, and edit the title if necessary.)

Question:

$\begin{array}{l}{\text { Let } C \text { be an } m \times n \text { matrix with real entries. For vectors } u, v \in \mathbb{R}^{m},} \\ {\text { we define } u \sim v \text { if there exists a vector } x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \text { such that } C x=u-v} \\ {\text { Prove that for all } u, v, w \in \mathbb{R}^{m}:} \\ {\text { i) } u \sim u} \\ {\text { ii) if } u \sim v \text { then } v \sim u} \\ {\text { iii) if } u \sim v \text { and } v \sim w \text { then } u \sim w} \end{array}$

Answer to i)

> $u \sim u \implies C\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{u} - \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{0}$ . We know that in all $R^{m} \ \exists \ \mathbf{0}_{n}$ , hence i) is trivially true

This is what I have scribbled down for ii)

> We have an implication. Hence, we need to show that if the LHS holds, then the RHS must hold.
> Let's assume that $u \sim v$ holds, then what does it mean?
>
> It means that if I have a matrix $C_{m\times n}$ and post-multiply it by a vector $\mathbf{x}_{n}$ then I can write the result as a linear combination of two vectors $\mathbf{u}_{m} , \mathbf{v}_{m}$
>
> $\mathbf{v} \sim \mathbf{u} \implies C\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{v} - \mathbf{u}$. But note that $\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{u} = -(\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v})$ , and then can be written as a linear combination of $\mathbf{u} \sim \mathbf{v}.$ Hence, $\mathbf{u} \sim \mathbf{v} \implies \mathbf{v} \sim \mathbf{u}$

Is this what is being asked for? If so, are there any giant leaps of logic?

Comment: For (i): You have to choose some $x$. Which one do you choose?

Comment: For (ii): You have to find $x$ such that $Cx = v-u$.

Comment: @amsmath By trivially true I meant that $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$, I've seen this expression often used for cases when a solution is 0. Is it not appropriate here?

Comment: Good. But you have to write it: "Choosing $x=0$ yields $Cx = 0 = u-u$, so $u\sim u$". Have you found the $x$ for (ii)?

Comment: @amsmath Right, I see. I think I can tell the imprecision now. So, instead of " then can be written as a linear combination of ∼" I should write. "which is just a linear combination of $(u-v)$ , and hence by writing $x$ as a linear comb $\lambda x$ , where $lambda = -1$. We have $u \sim v \implies v \sim u$ . Does it hold?

Comment: Why don't you just write it as it is? You choose $-x$. Short: we have $Cx = u-v$ for some $x$. So, $C(-x) = -Cx = -(u-v) = v-u$. Done.

Comment: For the third part: We have $Cx = u-v$ and $Cy = v-w$ for some $x$ and $y$. Then for which $z$ do we have $Cz = u-w$?

Comment: @amsmath Thanks for your help! The same style of 2 then, where we zet $z = (x+y)$ I imagine

Comment: Yes, correct, $z = x+y$. Very good! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get what you're trying to get at for the second part, but it feels a little ... floaty I guess? Like you yourself aren't sure. The third paragraph in addition feels like you initially assume the conclusion right off - you work backwards to the implication, which is fine sometimes, but a bit of a curveball to read. Whenever possible, try to start with your given premises, and work from them to your desired conclusion, as opposed to the other way around.

Let's say $\vec u \sim \vec v$. Then there exists some vector $\vec x$ for our fixed matrix $C$ such that $C\vec x = \vec u-\vec v$. With the premise as given, we want to show $\vec v \sim \vec u$.

We can augment the $\vec u \sim \vec v$ relation by multiplying through by $-1$ as so:

$$C\vec x = \vec u-\vec v = -(\vec v-\vec u) \implies C(-\vec x) = \vec v-\vec u$$

Thus, there exists some vector, namely $-\vec x$, such that $\vec v-\vec u$ is $C$ times that vector, giving $\vec v \sim \vec u$ whenever $\vec u \sim \vec v$.

Comment: Thanks, I envy this clear writing!! Also, if you don't mind, could you define what you mean by "augmenting the relation" and by "fixed matrix"?

Comment: There isn't a technical definition to those necessarily, it's more just how I tend to write. When I say I "augment the relation," I basically mean "let's take the original relation, and do things to it" (in the hope of obtaining our desired conclusion). As for the "fixed matrix" thing, that's just me clarifying that, per the problem's statement, the matrix $C$ has to be the same throughout this process. I would agree that the problem is sort of worded vaguely in that respect though, since sometimes people will think of it as "any $m \times n$ matrix of real entries" as opposed to a fixed one.